# How to catch selected text inside input?

Tags: reactjs

I have TextField(material-ui) and I need to catch what text user have selected.

For example I have text: I want to buy car.
User selected: want

How can I catch selected text and generate list component right after the text selection end?

Comment: Did you tried window.getSelection with  onmouseup event..?

Comment: @NaveenKerati no, but I will try

Answer (score 0):

Create an onchange function, and pass event parameter to the onchange function. This event parameter will hold the input element object, on doing event.target.value , you will get selected value. You can replace select with TextField.

```js
     function get_data(event){
            alert(event.target.value);
            }
```

```html
         <select id="data" onchange="get_data(event)">
                <option value="one">Option 1 Here</option> 
                <option value="two">Option 2 Here</option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Select extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        value:"",
    }
    this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
handleChange(e){
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })

}
render() {
    console.log(this.state.value);
    return (
        <select id="data" value={this.state.value} name="value" onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <option value="one">Option 1 Here</option> 
        <option value="two">Option 2 Here</option>
    </select>
    )
}
}
```

handleChange fire when option is selected! setting state.value to option value

Answer (score 0):

So, basically 2 options

1. pass the `onChange` function to your input and get its value from `event.target.value`
2. you can use refs to get the DOM node and there you can also get the value of the input (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element)